# given the input getting the wrong output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class printH 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.print("Please enter the height of H: ") ;
    int height = in.nextInt() ;
    int heightThird = findThird(height);
    int topBottom = printTopAndBottom(heightThird);
}
public static int findThird(int height3)
{
    if(height3>=4)
    {
        height3 = (height3 + 2) / 3 ;

    }
return height3 ;
}
public static int printTopAndBottom(int spacingH)
{
    String letterH = "H" ;
    String letterSpace = " " ;
    System.out.print(letterH) ;
    System.out.print(letterSpace)  ;
    System.out.println(letterSpace) ;
    return spacingH ; 
 }    
}
```

that is the code I have came up with so far but it has given me the wrong output

given the input of 10 the output should be

```
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
```

however I am getting the output

```
Please enter the height of H: H
```

Comment: why? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @FastSnail I think it's a homework

Comment: javahelp, you need a loop, the program executes line by line only once unless you use loops

Comment: findThird, given a integer for the total height of H, rounds the value up to the nearest multiple of 3 and then returns an ainter that is one third of that rounded height

Comment: then in printTopAndBottom i need to take that one third rounded height value and print the H with the width of the left, mid and right parts of H, being one third of the hight of H

Comment: @javahelp and why it should prints 8h four times?

Comment: yes it needs to bring it 4times because this is one third of the rounded height

Comment: and why it should print 8 h characters ?

Comment: @javahelp very unclear.nearest multiple of 3 for 10 is 9.i don't know why you expect this pattern

Comment: sorry it should round up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the line: `String letterH = "H" ;` so there can no `h` appear. And you need some loop which is used to print the correct amount of `h`.

There some simple code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.print("Please enter the height of H: ") ;
    int height = in.nextInt() ;
    int heightThird = findThird(height);
    for (int i = 0; i < heightThird; i++) {
        printTopAndBottom(heightThird);
    }
}

public static int findThird(int height3)
{
    if(height3 >= 4)
    {
        height3 = (height3 + 2) / 3 ;
    }
    return height3 ;
}

public static void printTopAndBottom(int spacingH)
{
    String line = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < spacingH; j++) {
        String currentChar = j % 2 == 0 ? "h" : " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < spacingH; i++) {
            line += currentChar;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: okay so i got it to work besides the output line Please enter the height of H:           there is supposed to be a 10 after the colon but this is not showing up

Comment: you have to enter the 10 by yourself